# Laravel QueryException: could not find driver in Alpine Linux

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to feature test my laravel application in CI. I however cannot get my migrations to run:

```
$ php artisan migrate
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 
  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:712
    708▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    709▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    710▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    711▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 712▕             throw new QueryException(
    713▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    714▕             );
    715▕         }
    716▕     }
      +33 vendor frames
```

In my CI I add the necessary drivers:

```
apk add php8-mysqli php8-pdo_mysql
```

Yet I still get the error.

I've tried to install php-mysql:

```
apk add php-mysql
```

But that gives the error:

```
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  php-mysql (no such package):
    required by: world[php-mysql]
```

Yet the package does exist: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.3/main/x86/php-mysql

How do I fix this?

Comment: That package is for PHP 5.6, not 8.

Comment: @aynber ah, that makes sense. What package do I need to install then?

Comment: If you do `php -v` on the command line, what do you get as the full version?

Comment: php -v gives: `php 8.1.2`

Comment: Try `php81-pdo_mysql` and `php81-mysqli`

Comment: `ERROR: unable to select packages: php81-mysqli (no such package): required by: world[php81-mysqli]`

`php81-pdo_mysql (no such package): required by: world[php81-pdo_mysql]`

Comment: did you run it with docker? if yes do it: The DB_HOST in `.env` should be the name of the service, ie, mysql: https://github.com/aschmelyun/docker-compose-laravel/blob/main/docker-compose.yml#L26